# What is the condition for $ ( \sqrt{a} - b )( \sqrt{a} + b ) $ to be 1?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I think its not a good level question, but I still have problem that what are the criteria for any two positive reals $ a , b $ so that, $$ ( \sqrt{a} - b )( \sqrt{a} + b ) = 1 $$

I need to know what type of numbers $ a $ and $ b $ need to be in order to satisfy the above equation.

(For instance: $ a $ should be prime, etc.)

**I found:**

• When any of $ a $ or $ b $ is equal to 1, this doesn't holds.

• When $ a $ is composite, then also ths doesn't holds.

Comment: is $a,b$ integers?

Comment: you forgot to add that, I guess

Comment: You in fact specifically said $a$ and $b$ are reals, rather than integers.

Comment: $a$ can be composite, e.g. $a=10$, $b=3$.

Comment: Infact, i need this not for integers, but for rationals too, thats why reals

Comment: @miracle173 plz delete your comment ..

Comment: @MANMAID see they are not int, delete your comment

Comment: @RaviPrakash if rational, write it, set of rations is a subset of set of reals

Comment: @MANMAID ok, Should i add +ve integers and rationals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$(\sqrt{a}-b)(\sqrt{a}+b)=a+\sqrt{a}b-b\sqrt{a}-b^2=a-b^2.$$  So this will equal $1$ iff $a=b^2+1$.  In particular, for each $b\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a unique $a\in\mathbb{R}$ which makes it true.  A number $a$ has the form $b^2+1$ for some $b\in \mathbb{R}$ iff $a\geq 1$ (in which case $b=\sqrt{a-1}$).

If you want to require $a$ and $b$ to be integers, the same condition holds: you need $a=b^2+1$.  There is again a unique choice of $a$ for each choice of $b$.  The possible values of $a$ are just all integers which are one more than a perfect square.  Note that such an $a$ certainly doesn't have to be prime: indeed, if $b>1$ is odd, then $b^2+1$ is even and greater than $2$ and therefore is never prime.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $( \sqrt{a} - b )( \sqrt{a} + b ) =a-b^2$.

Comment: Sir i asked about a & b, this thing i know

Answer (score 1):

Such points $(b,a)$ lies on parabolic curve $y=x^2 +1$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\sqrt a - b)(\sqrt a + b) = a -b^2=1 \iff a=b^2+1$$

Answer (score 0):

In the rationals, $b$ can be anything and $a$ must be a perfect square plus one.

In the reals, the only requirement is $a\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

$a$ and $b$ are related by a single real variable $u$ that allows to relate to other numbers

$$ a= \cosh^2 u,\, b= \sinh u .$$